Decompile/reverse engineer code to search for evidence of code stealing
Suppose I put part of the code of my software in a website (such as github) and let everyone see it so that they can suggest improvement or report vulnerability in the software. However, at the same time, the software is a paid software, so I dont want people to use the code without paying, and I don't want people to use my code in their software either.
Now suppose, for various reason, I suspect that someone have been using my code in their software without my permission. I bought/obtain for free their software and obtain the right to use it. I don't have access to the source code of the software, so my only way to obtain evidence of them stealing my code is to decompile and reverse engineer the code. However, the license of the software explicitly prohibit decompiling and reverse engineering of the software.
So my question is, with the scenario above, is it legal for me to decompile and reverse engineer their software code to see if they steal my code or not ?
Now lets continue with the assumption that the answer to question above is No. Suppose it is not legal for me to decompile and reverse engineer the software. This means that I have zero way to legally get evidence of them stealing my code.
I thought, if I can't get the evidence, maybe the court can ? So, can i sue someone for code stealing, without giving any evidence, and ask the court to check their software code to see if they actually steal my code or not? And what kind of punishment I might receive from the court if it turns out they didn't steal my code?
I generally want the answer to all the question above for all country. However, that would be too broad, so to minimize the scope of this question, I want the answer for US country.

reverse engineering doesn't guarantee you can match what you find to your original code. Source -> machine code is not a 1:1 conversation (unless your code is assembly).

Pretty sure that a license term banning reverse engineering and decompiling is void as contrary to public policy, especially under the First Sale doctrine, but I don't have the time today to confirm and substantiate that intuition.

So, to be clear, you make your software publicly available and ask people to look at it and help improve it, then try to find some way to sue people because they may have looked at it?

I'm sure there are duplicates of this. I think the gist of the answer is that if you sue them for copyright infringement, you can use the discovery process to demand the source code.

@JonCuster Yes, there are a number of companies and licenses to this effect. This provides transparency without providing the IP to the end-user or community. Consider also software patents, where the protected idea is necessarily described publicly.

@littleadv yes there is no guarantee i can match what i find with my software code, but there is still a possibility that i can. Just because there is no guarantee, doesn't mean the possibility didn't exist.

@JonCuster You misunderstood, in the scenario i described above, i'm not suing people for looking at my code, i'm suing people for stealing my code (if i deem worth it to sue). As user71659 have mentioned, what i want to do is to provide transparancy without providing the IP, which is my software.

To elaborate on @littleadv's comment, you could easily find something that does "match with your software code," but even then there would still be the possibility that some different source code resulted in the same binary code.  To prove copyright infringement, you would have a further burden of proof to show (probably to a "balance of probabilities" or "preponderance of the evidence" standard) that the binary code was actually compiled from source code that had been copied from your GitHub repository.

I suggest it can't matter that the license… prohibit decompiling and reverse engineering of the software.
In purely commercial use, fine… and do you think the license could prohibit any authority decompiling or reverse-engineering anything?


I thought, if I can't get the evidence, maybe the court can ? So, can i sue someone for code stealing, without giving any evidence, and ask the court to check their software code to see if they actually steal my code or not?

You can't ask the court to check their code for you, but you can ask the court to compel them to give you a copy of their source code, allowing you to check it yourself, through a process known as discovery.  This would be the actual source code of the software that you suspect of infringing your copyright, obviating any need for decompilation.  To avoid abuse of this process, you have to be able to establish some reasonable prospect of success before the court will compel the defendant to disclose its private documents to you.
Potentially more useful still, you could obtain records of internal communications.  For example, you could search any e-mail or chat records for mentions of your GitHub repository or for messages saying "let's use this code we found on GitHub."
Conversely, the evidence might show that the defendants had in fact engaged in a rigorous clean-room reverse engineering exercise to avoid copyright infringement of your code (though if that were the case the defendant would probably have presented the evidence of their own volition in their initial response to your lawsuit).

And what kind of punishment I might receive from the court if it turns out they didn't steal my code?

Generally there is no punishment as such for pursuing an unsuccessful lawsuit.  Depending on the jurisdiction and on the circumstances, you may be required to cover the defendants' costs, however, which can be very expensive indeed.  If the basis of your lawsuit is particularly flimsy, especially if it is lacking altogether, you could be punished by the court for frivolous litigation.  This becomes increasingly likely if you file similar suits repeatedly.  It would also be more likely if there is evidence showing that you are using the courts to burden the defendant.
However, if you are reasonably seeking in good faith to vindicate your rights, there should be no talk of punishment.
My understanding is that discovery is particular to common-law jurisdictions, but I presume that similar mechanisms exist in other systems to achieve similar ends.
